# How to install Pycharm with bash in Mint? in a way icon would be added to program list

Tags: linux, bash, linux-mint

I recently installed Intellj Idea on Linux mint with running this command in terminal:

```
cd bin 
./idea.sh
```

then the Intellj idea installed perfectly and app icon was added in my program list.

but when i do the same for Pycharm, after i run the command

```
cd bin
./pycharm.sh
```

it runs perfectly but the difference is no app icon is added to my program list and i should run this command every time i need Pycharm.

What is the deference here that next one won't add app icon ?

Answer (score 0):

this question has already been answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/391439/how-can-i-set-up-pycharm-to-launch-from-the-launcher).

Also, I recommend you start getting used to install programs using your distro's package manager. Pycharm and Intelj Idea are both located on Debian's unofficial repo. Here is some [learning material for you to start at](https://itsfoss.com/apt-command-guide/).

Comment: Thank you, i saw it in Software Manager, but for some reasons it was like 1.2 GB! So i download the package from website for only 200mb